# What is difference between Array and Binary search tree in efficiency?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree, processing-efficiency

I want know what is the best : Array OR Binary search tree in ( insert , delete , find max and min ) and how can I Improve both of them ?

Comment: Did you try searching for this information? It should be easy to find.

Comment: Do you mean the abstract data structures [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)?

Comment: improve in what way? the best for what? those are completely different data structures, and each of them might be the 'best' for a certain application.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An **array** allows [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) to each element in it. so you get insert, delete and look for a specific element in `O(1)`, and max/min, delete in `O(n)`. [you can also make max/min `O(1)` and delete `O(n)` instead]. If you are keeping your array sorted, it will cause insert/delete to be `O(n)`, but you will gain `O(logn)` find, and `O(1)` min/max.

A **BST** is sorted by definition, and for a regular [unbalanced] BST, you get `O(n)` worst case behavior. For **balanced BST**, you get `O(logn)` insert/delete/find.  You can get  `O(1)` min/max any how for both.

Arrays are also usually faster to [iterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration) [assuming order of iteration is not important] since you gain better [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache) performance. Also, unlike BST - which has unbounded size by nature, an array requires reallocation and copying the data when your array is full.

**Improving** a BST can be done by making it [balanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) - like [AVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [red-black-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

**Which is better**? it depends on the application. Usually when you are planning to insert data and keep it sorted, BST will be prefered. If random access or iteration is the main purpose: you usually use an array.

Comment: Why is the `findMin/findMax` constant operations `O(1)` for a balanced BST?

Comment: @user384706: Whenever you insert/remove an element from a balanced BST, it is `O(logn)` and `O(n)` for non balanced BST. You can maintain extra pointers `min` and `max`, which will only be modified when you insert/remvoe elements from the BST. Finding the new maximum/minimum is `O(logn)` for balanced BST and `O(n)` for non balanced - thus there is no performance loss [big O terms] in this operation, and in terms of big O, you can maintain these pointers for "free"

Comment: Ah,so you mean use extra pointers.But in this case, this is an optimization not directly related to the BST algorithms.So isn't it somewhat inconsistent/misleading to claim in a comparison with another data structure (in this case an array) that the `max/min` is `O(1)` since it isn't by default?One must implement it such that it is

Comment: @user384706: I explicitly said that you **can get** it: `You can get O(1) min/max any how for both.` The idea is this enhancement is "free" in terms of big O notation - and if you need min/max: there is no reason not to do it. However, in comparing to non-sorted array [the topic of this thread]: you cannnot do both O(1) insertion and O(1) min/max , thus it is important to mention the fact that you *can* get `O(1)` max/min with BST for "free".

Answer (score 18):

Performance comparison of Arrays and Binary search trees:

```
                 Array                     Binary search tree
          Unsorted   Sorted           Average            Worst case
Space      O(n)       O(n)             O(n)               O(n)
Search     O(n)       O(log n) *       O(log n)           O(n)
Max/Min    O(n)       O(1)             O(1) **            O(1) **
Insert     O(1)       O(n)             O(log n)           O(n)
Delete     O(1)       O(n)             O(log n)           O(n)
```

`*` assuming binary search

`**` requires extra pointers to min and max, otherwise it's O(log n)

Comment: Why is `O(1)` the find max/min of a BST?

Comment: Now that you ask, I'm not sure if it is correct. Binary Search Trees are sorted by definition, but (depending on the implementation?) it may not be possible to get the min/max in O(1). In that case it would be O(log n) instead.

Comment: It is not `O(1)` unless your implementation keeps a pointer to the `min` and `max` values.Check also comments in the answer of amit